# Ping a server + progress bar then display a different div

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, ping

So basically I am using Bootstrap 3 RC2. I want to be able to ping a server via PHP. I found this script on google.

```
<?php
// Script by Akensai

if (!$socket = @fsockopen("YOUR.IP.HERE", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
  echo "<font color='red'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
}
else 
{
  echo "<font color='green'><strong>Online!/strong></font>";


  fclose($socket);
}

?>
```

I know I can just change the online/offline echo to a bootstrap element such as a 100% progress bar.

What I'd like to know is how can I make the progress bar go from 0%-100% when pinging the servers. By default, the progress bar will be blue when loading, if there is a success it will change to green, if it fails, then it will change to red. Bootstrap offers these options by just simply changing the classes in the progress bar DIV's.

I know this may seem impractical being as ping is generally really fast, but still, i'd like to know how to use that feature for future reference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to use ajax to ping then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am going to demonstrate to you how its done with just jquery, i haven't used bootstrap much.

first let's assume we have server code that does similar to what your doing.

```
$json = array();
if ($socket = fsockopen($_POST['ip'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
   $json = array('status' => 1);
   fclose($socket);
} else {
   $json = array('status' => 0);
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($json);
```

We have a server script that we can call from the client end that will return us a json response.

On the html side we have the following progress bar.

```
<progress id='progress' max=100></progress>
```

Then we have the following jquery code that calls our script

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
         url: '/script.php',
         data: { ip : '127.0.0.1' },
         type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
           if (json.status  == 1) $("#progress").val($('#progress').val() + 10);
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

You will need to make this ajax call using `setInterval` or another queuing method so it pings until the ping is completed.
Note that i removed the `@` from your `fsockopen` this is a bad practice to have. [Read](http://themessycode.blogspot.com/2013/08/cost-of-error-suppression-and-ignorance.html)

Comment: I hate having to say this, and be language ignorant to a person knowledgeable to a language.
I do not understand any of what you wrote, meaning.. where I put that code, where I save which to what. I know this is not the place to ask to be spoon fed, I know.
Like I said, I hate the fact that I am saying this, as I'm pretty sure this aggravates you and others reading this, but I have no idea of how json/js/php works. I only know HTML and CSS at the moment. I am soon to undergo training in PHP.
Until then I must rely on people 'spoon feeding' me to just get along with the ideas I have in mind.

Comment: @AshleyBrown i clearly stated which is php and which is client side :)

Comment: Then for the HTML the markup is
`<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
</div>`
The only thing needed to change the percentage of the completion is to just change the style="width:40%" to what percentage of completion is needed.
But as a side note, the markup for the progress is different to what you presumed, so ..yeah I'm all over the place here.. would it be possible to help me via email or skype or something?

Thankyou very much for how you have helped me so far.

Comment: @DevZerO I tweeted at you and followed you, I am unable to DM you as you do not follow me.